# Is there a locationChange equlivent for PhoneGap InAppBrowser like in ChildBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, childbrowser, inappbrowser

I am trying to use Google OAuth2 for Google Drive authentication on both Android and iOS. I had a solution working on Android using ChildBrowser, but it did not work on iOS. PhoneGap Build support suggested I use InAppBrowser because ChildBrowser is depreciated.

I can get iOS and Android both to prompt my user for ID/PW then it shows "Allow Access" button all in InAppBrowser to give Googl Drive access. On Android tapping Allow Access button gives page not available error with correct code and OAuth token in the url. When using childbrowser it was this change event that allowed you to check for code 4 and get the token. InAppBrowser only has LoadStart, LoadStop and Exit events.

How can I check the Google return URL for success/failure and if success grab the token?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I use InAppBrowser to do Facebook auth. Since you're just trying to grab a value out of the url, it should work the same way:

```
var fb = {
    id: '...'
    ,secret: '...'
    ,namespace: '...'
    ,redirect: '...'
    ,display: 'touch'
    ,scope: ['publish_actions']

    ,windowRef: null
    ,code: null
    ,onLoadEvent: function(event){
        var url = event.url;
        console.log(url);

        //once we've been redirected to this domain, fb's job is done
        if (/my.domain.com/.test(url)){

            if (/code=/.test(url)){
                //auth done
                var code = url.match(/code=([^\&]+)/)
                if (code) code = code[1];
                window.fb.code = code;
                window.fb.windowRef.close();
            }else if (/error_description=/.test(url)){
                //login unsuccessful
                var error = url.match(/error_description=([^\&]+)/);
                if (error) error = error[1].replace(/[^A-Z0-9 ]/gi, " ");
                console.error("facebook login failed: " + error);
                window.fb.code = null;
                window.fb.windowRef.close();
            }

        }
    }
};

var authUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
            + "client_id=" + fb.id
            + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(fb.redirect)
            + "&display=" + fb.display
            + "&scope=" + fb.scope.join('%2C');

fb.windowRef = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', loginPopupOptions);

//no reason we can't use the same function twice...
fb.windowRef.addEventListener('loadstart', fb.onLoadEvent);
fb.windowRef.addEventListener('loadstop', fb.onLoadEvent);
```

I tried to pull only the relevant bits out of our structure so hopefully it makes sense this way...